# Multi Level Nested Queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a multi-level nested document. I want to query based on multiple nested queries with all the conditions must match.

Example

Document 1

```
{
    "publishing_rule": {
        "publishing_orders": [{
                "transporters": [{
                    "fteid": "81"
                }],
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "transporters": [{
                    "fteid": "82"
                }],
                "active": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Document 2

```
{
    "publishing_rule": {
        "publishing_orders": [{
                "transporters": [{
                    "fteid": "81"
                }],
                "active": true
            },
            {
                "transporters": [{
                    "fteid": "82"
                }],
                "active": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to fetch all the documents which match below condition

```
publishing_rule.publishing_orders.active = true 

AND 

publishing_rule.publishing_orders.transporters.fteid = '81'
```

Both `active` and `transporters.fteid` should be part of same object.

I have tried creating below mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "publishing_rule.publishing_orders": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "transporters": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And used below query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "publishing_rule.publishing_orders",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.active": true
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.transporters",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.transporters.fteid": "81"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But I am not getting expected result. The query returning both the documents.

I am expecting only Document 2 in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query actually will look at any document that matches either `active = true` or `fteid = 81` but not both of them. Those criteria are met in document 1 and document 2. That's why you got those two.

This query should work

```js
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "publishing_rule.publishing_orders",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.active": true
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.transporters",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.transporters.fteid": "81"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that I use a single `nested` as entry point then inner `nested`, this is to enable two filters altogether to search in the document.

**UPDATE**

mapping

```js
GET /myindex/_mapping

{
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "publishing_rule": {
            "properties": {
              "publishing_orders": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                  "active": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  },
                  "transporters": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                      "fteid": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                          "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

ES result

Document 2

```js
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.89712,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "AWzu__bgqsCjtPMt7kG_",
        "_score": 1.89712,
        "_source": {
          "publishing_rule": {
            "publishing_orders": [
              {
                "transporters": [
                  {
                    "fteid": "81" // matched
                  }
                ],
                "active": true // matched
              },
              {
                "transporters": [
                  {
                    "fteid": "82"
                  }
                ],
                "active": true
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The above query is also giving both the documents in the result.

Comment: This is my field mapping
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "publishing_rule.publishing_orders": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "transporters": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @OnkarKore interesting. I used your mapping and get document 2 as a result. I have updated my answer to include my mapping and search result.

Comment: In my example `81` is actually `COM-5fbd027b-c154-46b7-b887-0b9c37438c81` which was getting tokenized and not able to do an exact match. So I am not able to get a proper response. I changed the mapping from `text` to `keyword`. Your answer works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I saw that @deerawan answer is adequate to the question that you have asked. Since you didn't accept his answer, I believe what you are looking for is to get the nested document alone in the result. I have modified @deerawan's query to include the nested document alone that gets matched by the query

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "publishing_rule.publishing_orders",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.active": true
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.transporters",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "publishing_rule.publishing_orders.transporters.fteid": "81"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  }
}
```

This should give you the below response

```
{
  "took": 7,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.3862944,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "nest",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "1234",
        "_score": 1.3862944,
        "inner_hits": {
          "publishing_rule.publishing_orders": {
            "hits": {
              "total": 1,
              "max_score": 1.3862944,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "publishing_rule.publishing_orders",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.3862944,
                  "_source": {
                    "transporters": [
                      {
                        "fteid": "81"
                      }
                    ],
                    "active": true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```